# Place Text Inside CKEditor Footer

Tags: php, javascript, editor, ckeditor, fckeditor

On the footer inside the CK Editor (which normally shows the html element you are currently selected on) is there a way to place additional text inside there). There is a lot of extra space on the right hand side and I would like to place a "Last Edited" phase in that location but can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.ui.space( 'bottom' )` will give you the element that holds the bottom space. You can append anything you want here with JS + CSS.